# Autoselect current website in dropdown menu using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple office websites that use the same navigational dropdown menu in the page header to allow site visitors to easily jump to another office website. I have designed the dropdown menu, but I am unsure how to approach the server side coding aspect so the dropdown menu knows what is the active office page the visitor is currently on. I have 3 office websites:

- Office Location 1
- Office Location 2
- Office Location 3

My menu structure is: (also [**JSFIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrf81u0c/))

```
<section id="ad_banner" class="container">
<div class="network">
<span class="abc_network">ABC Services</span>
    <div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle">Office Location 1   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="1" href="index-header2.php">Office Location 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="1" href="index-header3.php">Office Location 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rather than having to update all the office pages manually when new office locations are added, I want to include the dropdown code into my office page template (I'll use a PHP include unless someone has another suggestion). I'm guessing I'll add a php variable at the top of each office location page like $page = "office location 1" and then add it to the global dropdown menu code somehow. I just don't know how to have the dropdown menu autoselect the page. Help!

Comment: A simple if statement will solve your problem for eg: `if ($page == 'site1.php') { echo 'class="active"';}` you can assign `$page` variable with `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

I used an iframe to achieve this.

Edited:  Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yrf81u0c/5/

The iframe code:

```
<iframe src="#" width=100% height= 500px>
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

The Jquery:

```
 $('a').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();   
 var site = $(this).attr("href");
 $('iframe').attr("src",site);
 var value = $(this).text();
 $("#top").text(value);

});
```

Comment: iFrames are ugly and, in the OP's case, provide nothing advantageous.

Comment: @Sparky, I really don't use iframes much, but I don't see any other way to solve Ops problem, being that he wants to keep the header static. I don't know much about ajax, but maybe that could work also.

Comment: What's wrong with a template?  After all, WordPress is PHP, has a common header/footer, and does not use iFrames, as only one simple example to make my point.  In fact, the OP says nothing about a "static" header and specifically mentions using a template.

Comment: @Sparky Maybe I'm just confused by the question. Wordpress is like any other site with a common header/footer, I know that! What I meant was a static header with options to take you to 3 different web pages, not 3 different sub-pages within the same website (that would obviously have the same header/footer, except in rare cases).